# How to prevent "sourceMappingURL" removal when using Stylelint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, stylelint

I customize Bootstrap 4 with node-sass and autoprefixer

My next step is to use **Stylelint** to set properly indentation

My `.stylelintrc.json` file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "indentation": 2
  }
}
```

The problem is that Stylelint deletes the last line in the file it contains:

`/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */`

How to prevent "sourceMappingURL" removal when using the stylelint?

I can't find the right Stylelint rule for this in doc.

Comment: As you opened an issue( #4667) with stylelint we close it here

Comment: OK thank you. After resolving this in the repository, I will answer myself here to help other people